# Can't get max function to work correctly

Tags: python

```
print('File Number Analyzer')
with open("randomNumbers.txt", 'r') as f:
    randomNumbers=f.readlines()
print(randomNumbers)
maxN = max[randomNumbers]
print(maxN)
```

The purpose of this program is to utilize a file created by another program I designed that has a list of random numbers.

I was able to display the list without a problem, but when trying to use the max function to find the maximum number in the list, I keep either getting an error stating that the max function is not subscriptable or if I use `()` around the list for the max function instead of `[]` it simply displays the entire list again, not the max number.

I have looked at several of the posts on this site and they all say to do the function this way or with `()`, so what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you share the output this generates?

Comment: The indentation is correct now, the code is like this in Pycharm as well.

Comment: You didn't actually parse the file. You have a list of lines, not a list of numbers.

Comment: Can you provide a sample of the contents of the file?

Comment: I do have a list of numbers and I know I do because I can print them in the console just fine.

Comment: The randomNumbers.txt file contains this list of numbers: 298 360 56 295 393 148 370 478 239 361. Nothing is in the file except the numbers.

Answer (score 0):

1. You should call `max` with `()`, and not with `[]`.
2. `readlines()` returns a list of strings. In order to use `max` on it you should cast everything in it to an `int` or `float`:

   ```
   maxN = max([int(num) for num in randomNumbers])
   print(maxN)
   ```

Comment: I've used both () and [] because I've seen both used depending on the situation, but your line of code doesn't work either. I'm getting an error saying "invalid literal for int()"

Comment: @KevinB There is no situation where `max[]` is a valid call in Python unless you actually created a list called max, which should not be done either.

Comment: Regardless, your code displays the error I stated in the previous comment.

Comment: @KevinB Then you will need to check the content of your file. It might not be what you expect it to be. "invalid literal for int()" means your file doesn't contain only numbers.

Comment: Well that is not true because I have the file open on my computer right now and the contents are simply a list of numbers with a space between each, nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you have a list of `str`s, not a list of `int`s. Max won't work right on strings, if I recall correctly. You need to convert `randomNumbers` into a list of `int`s. Replace

```
randomNumbers=f.readlines()
```

with this

```
randomNumbers = [int(i) for i in f.readlines()]
```

and it should work.

Call `max` like this:

```
max(randomNumbers)
```

Don't use square brackets to call functions.

Comment: Doesn't work, shows error saying "invalid literal for int()"

Comment: @KevinB It worked on my computer with a text file of just numbers. Can you show the format of `randomNumbers.txt`?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is based on how your file is set up.

You are dealing with a space delimited file:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6
```

So, what happens when you use `readlines` is that your content comes back like this:

```
['1 2 3 4 5 6 7']
```

A list with a string who's contents are spaced. Which is not what you want. You want something like this:

```
['1', '2', '3', etc...]
```

What I suggest you do if you do not want to modify the contents of your file, is use `read()` instead of `readlines()` which will give you a string instead of a list. From there you use `split()` on the string which creates a list out of a string using the space as the delimiter by default.

Furthermore, you should make sure you typecast your data to int. So the easiest thing is to use a comprehension to create a list of ints.

So, really the only line of code you have to change is how you are reading the file, and make sure like others have mentioned, that you use `max()` and not `max[]`.

After creating a file like this:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

---

```
print('File Number Analyzer')
with open("t.txt", 'r') as f:
    randomNumbers = [int(i) for i in f.read().split()]
print(randomNumbers)
maxN = max(randomNumbers)
print(maxN)
```